# Get a non-ambiguous boolean from DataFrame - python3

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, module, jupyter-notebook, valueerror

I wrote simple codes as follows, where df_row is a DataFrame that has only booleans(True or False) in it.

DataFrame looks like this,

```
                     Load_Avg  Load_Avg_difference  WaterLevel(cm)  ...
TIMESTAMP                                                           
2016-06-25 05:00:00      True                False           False  ...
```

```
hold_id = []
for j, colname in enumerate(colnames):
    if df_row[colname].bool():
        hold_id.append(j)

        break
```

Now I want to break when there's True boolean in df_row by checking the boolean in order.

I always get an Error saying

`ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I used .bool() to check if the DataFrame is True or False, right? I'm confused...

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to iterate over each column and check if any value in that column is True. if so then break from the loop?

Comment: @ abhilb Sorry it was not clear. I just added some codes so I hope you will understand what I want to do here. I want to know the column number of the first appeared True in df_row. With the data above, the first appeared True is in Load_Avg column, whose column number is 0, so store it in  hold_id.

Answer (score 0):

`df_row[colname]` returns a series.
`bool` function Return the bool of a single element PandasObject.

So you cannot call the bool function on Pandas series.

If you want to check if all the items in the series are True, you can use 
`df_row[colname].all()`

If you want to check if any of the items in the series are True, you can use
`df_row[colname].any()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I didn't mention here but I want to know the number of the first appeared True from the left most column. That's why I used for loop to iterate them one by one.